# Is there any software to allow "Visual Programming" to code iOS apps?

Tags: ios, programming

Is there any software to allow Visual Programming on Xcode? By "Visual Programming" I mean the type of software that allows you to drag blocks to code. Lego MindStorms is a software that does this. I know its not built in to the application but I'm wondering if there is any software that you can download from the internet that would allow you to do that.

Comment: Not quite what you are after, but if you want visual programming for kids on the iPad Scratch Junior is good http://www.scratchjr.org/

Comment: The concept is there, but I'm not sure id be able to program a fully fledged iPhone application with that. I doubt there is something that does what I'm after. Anyways thanks for the suggestion. @MatthewLock

Comment: Yes it's just for kids to play around with visual programming rather than making apps. In a similar vain to Scratch is Hopscotch http://www.gethopscotch.com/